# What does "splitter" attribute in sklearn's DecisionTreeClassifier do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

The sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier has a attribute called "splitter" , it is set to "best" by default, what does setting it to "best" or "random" do? I couldn't find enough information from the official documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is 2 things to consider, the `criterion` and the `splitter`. During all the explaination, I'll use the wine dataset example:

**Criterion:**

It is used to evaluate the feature importance. The default one is `gini` but you can also use `entropy`. Based on this, the model will define the importance of each feature for the classification.

*Example*:

The wine dataset using a "gini" criterion has a feature importance of:

```
                             alcohol -> 0.04727507393151268
                          malic_acid -> 0.0
                                 ash -> 0.0
                   alcalinity_of_ash -> 0.0
                           magnesium -> 0.0329784450464887
                       total_phenols -> 0.0
                          flavanoids -> 0.1414466773122087
                nonflavanoid_phenols -> 0.0
                     proanthocyanins -> 0.0
                     color_intensity -> 0.0
                                 hue -> 0.08378677906228588
        od280/od315_of_diluted_wines -> 0.3120425747831769
                             proline -> 0.38247044986432716
```

The wine dataset using a "entropy" criterion has a feature importance of:

```
                             alcohol -> 0.014123729330936566
                          malic_acid -> 0.0
                                 ash -> 0.0
                   alcalinity_of_ash -> 0.02525179137252771
                           magnesium -> 0.0
                       total_phenols -> 0.0
                          flavanoids -> 0.4128453371544815
                nonflavanoid_phenols -> 0.0
                     proanthocyanins -> 0.0
                     color_intensity -> 0.22278576133186542
                                 hue -> 0.011635633063349873
        od280/od315_of_diluted_wines -> 0.0
                             proline -> 0.31335774774683883
```

Results varies with the `random_state` so I think that only a subset of the dataset is used to compute it.

**Splitter:**

The splitter is used to decide which feature and which threshold is used.

- Using `best`, the model if taking the feature with the highest importance
- Using `random`, the model if taking the feature randomly but with the same distribution (in `gini`, `proline` have an importance of 38% so it will be taken in 38% of cases)

*Example:*

After training 1000 `DecisionTreeClassifier` with `criterion="gini", splitter="best"` and here is the distribution of the "feature number" used at the first split and the 'threshold'

[image: feature selection distribution]

It always choses the feature 12 (=`proline`) with a `threshold` of 755. This is the head of one of the model trained:

[image]

By doing the same with `splitter= "random"`, the result is:

[image]

The threshold is more variant due to the use of different features, here is the result by filtering model having the feature 12 as first split:

[image]

We can see that the model is also taking randomply the `threshold`to split. By looking at the distribution of the feature 12 in regards of classes, we have:

[image]

The red line being the `threshold` used when `splitter="best"`.
Now, using random, the model will randomly select a `threshold` value (I think normally distributed with a mean/stdev of the feature but I'm not sure) leading the a distribution centered in the green light and with min max in blue (done with 1353 randomly trained model wtarting with feature 12 for the split)

[image]

#### Code to reproduce:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, plot_tree, _tree
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wine = datasets.load_wine()

# Feature importance

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="gini", splitter='best', random_state=42)
clf = clf.fit(wine.data, wine.target)

for name, val in zip(wine.feature_names, clf.feature_importances_):
    print(f"{name:>40} -> {val}")

print("")
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy", splitter='best', random_state=42)
clf = clf.fit(wine.data, wine.target)

for name, val in zip(wine.feature_names, clf.feature_importances_):
    print(f"{name:>40} -> {val}")

# Feature selected first and threshold

features = []
tresholds = []
for random in range(1000):
    clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="gini", splitter='best', random_state=random)
    clf = clf.fit(wine.data, wine.target)
    features.append(clf.tree_.feature[0])
    tresholds.append(clf.tree_.threshold[0])

# plot distribution
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 5))
ax.hist(features, bins=np.arange(14)-0.5)
ax2.hist(tresholds)
ax.set_title("Number of the first used for split")
ax2.set_title("Value of the threshold")
plt.show()

# plot model
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 12))
plot_tree(clf) 
plt.show()

# plot filtered result
threshold_filtered = [val for feat, val in zip(features, tresholds) if feat==12]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(20, 10))
ax.hist(threshold_filtered)
ax.set_title("Number of the first used for split")
plt.show()

feature_number = 12
X1, X2, X3 = wine.data[wine.target==0][:, feature_number], wine.data[wine.target==1][:, feature_number], wine.data[wine.target==2][:, feature_number]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title(f'feature {feature_number} - distribution')
ax.boxplot([X1, X2, X3])
ax.hlines(755, 0.5, 3.5, colors="r", linestyles="dashed")
ax.hlines(min(threshold_filtered), 0.5, 3.5, colors="b", linestyles="dashed")
ax.hlines(max(threshold_filtered), 0.5, 3.5, colors="b", linestyles="dashed")
ax.hlines(sum(threshold_filtered)/len(threshold_filtered), 0.5, 3.5, colors="g", linestyles="dashed")
plt.xlabel("Class")
plt.show()
```

Comment: So If I choose "random",the Gini impurity or the Information gain will not be calculated? because calculating them and using "random" doesn't make any sense,Am I right?

Comment: I guess it will be calculated afterward but not used to select the best feature.

Comment: This answer seems to be wrong. The random splitter goes through all features. For every feature it tests only at one random split between min and max of that feature.

Comment: You are right, I maybe mixed up between criterion and splitter. I'll investigate and edit the answer this week end.

Comment: @John, I've completely restarted the explanation with more details and I hope this is now clearer and with less mistakes (the only points I don't get is exactly how the `threshold` value is selected in `random`. Some approximation were due to lack of knowledge (I wrote this answer less than a year after starting the Data Science)

Comment: @NicolasM. The answer is now much better, but I still prefer the one from JSong, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56999837/2414411 because it just answers the question in a clipped and precise way. There are still flaws with your answer: "gini" and "entropy" are choices for the metric, which evaluates a score for each split, comparable with "RMSE" for regression problems. I like the example you give, but it does not make clear that `random` goes through every feature. It even sounds like it did not by saying "Using random, the model is taking the feature randomly [...]".

Comment: From what I understood, in ´random´ the model is just evaluating the metric for each feature and then pick one randomly (with probabilities based on the metric). This can be seen in the 3rd plot on the left. The distribution is very similar to the gini score. (on 1000 model fitted, it has chosen the feature 12 for the first split around 300 times which is quite similar to the gini score of the proline of 38%)

Answer (score 7):

***Short ans:***

RandomSplitter initiates a **random split on each chosen feature**, whereas BestSplitter goes through **all possible splits on each chosen feature**.

---

***Longer explanation:***

This is clear when you go thru _splitter.pyx.

RandomSplitter calculates improvement only on threshold that is randomly initiated (ref. lines 761 and 801). BestSplitter goes through all possible splits in a while loop (ref. lines 436 (which is where loop starts) and 462). *[Note: Lines are in relation to version 0.21.2.]*

As opposed to earlier responses from 15 Oct 2017 and 1 Feb 2018, **RandomSplitter and BestSplitter both loop through all relevant features**. This is also evident in _splitter.pyx.

Answer (score 2):

The "Random" setting selects a feature at random, then splits it at random and calculates the gini. It repeats this a number of times, comparing all the splits and then takes the best one.

This has a few advantages:

1. It's less computation intensive than calculating the optimal split of every feature at every leaf.
2. It should be less prone to overfitting.
3. The additional randomness is useful if your decision tree is a component of an ensemble method.

Comment: This seems to be wrong. The random splitter goes through all features. For every feature it tests only at one random split between min and max of that feature.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the "random" parameter is used for implementing the extra randomized tree in sklearn. In a nutshell, this parameter means that the splitting algorithm will traverse all features but only randomly choose the splitting point between the maximum feature value and the minimum feature value. If you are interested in the algorithm's details, you can refer to this paper [1]. Moreover, if you are interested in the detailed implementation of this algorithm, [you can refer to this page](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/8ea176ae0ca535cdbfad7413322bbc3e54979e4d/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx).

[1]. P. Geurts, D. Ernst., and L. Wehenkel, “Extremely randomized trees”, Machine Learning, 63(1), 3-42, 2006.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion,

1. JSong's explanation (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56999837) is correct,
2. Nicolas M.'s experiment (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46759065) verifies JSong's explanation.

My Reason:

If the algorithm randomly selects a point to split for all features, and then chooses the feature with the best performance. Those features that are more important have a greater probability of being selected (**The proline's importance is 38%, even with random selection of the split point, it still has a 38% chance of being the best feature**).

Conclusion:

1. If using **"best"**, for all features, the algorithm selects the **"best"** point to split, then choose the best feature as the final decision.
2. If using **"random"**, for all features, the algorithm **"randomly"** selects a point to split, then choose the best feature as the final decision.